# Need to fetch one field in MongoDB using eclipse in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to fetch a particular field in mongo. Now this field is included in many objects so we might need to run an array also I need to narrow it down to some particular text. I was able to get all the fields but I don't seem to be able to get just one field.

```
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(PAH TO MONGO);

    System.out.println(mongo.getDatabaseNames());  
    DB db= mongo.getDB(DB NAME); 
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection(COLLECTION NAME);
    BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();

DBCursor cursor= coll.find(whereQuery); 

    while (cursor.hasNext())
    { 
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }
```

IS ALSO TRIED

```
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(PAH TO MONGO);

    System.out.println(mongo.getDatabaseNames());  
    DB db= mongo.getDB(DB NAME); 
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection(COLLECTION NAME);
    BasicDBObject searchQuery= new BasicDBObject();
             //FIELD NAME
             searchQuery.getString("Url");  
           DBCursor cursor= coll.find(searchQuery); 

    while (cursor.hasNext())
    { 
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }
```

I also need to filter the data with some partial text lets say a url field with `http://yahoo.com/@#%##$`, but this is a partial url so I need to make sure I get yahoo.com and whatever is after it, because there is other data besides just yahoo.com.

The reason why I need this is because I need to deposit the url I get from mongo into a variable and then use that variable in a loop to run through each url and run automated testing.

It will be great if someone can help me out.

Thanks,

Mediha

Answer (score 3):

The `cursor.next()` statement returns a `DBObject` instance. Therefore, you can assign it to a variable and then invoke the [DBObject#get(String key)](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.12/org/bson/BSONObject.html#get%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Also, a cast to the `BasicDBObject` class may be necessary, if you want to have a MongoDB specific bson object.

For example:

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) { 
    BasicDBObject next = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
    Object someField = next.get("someField");
    //more stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks A lot this was simpler than I thought I will just figure out the filteration.

Comment: @Madi, you can accept my asnwer if you find it useful. :)